# Spring batch job execution error: cannot insert NULL into (BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION.START_TIME)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-cloud-task

I am newbie to learn spring batch framework with spring cloud. I created a simple batch job to read records from database. It seems that job failed when it tried to save job execution into database. Please advise what have been missing. Thanks.

The main application code is below:

```
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.task.configuration.EnableTask;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTask
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchCloudApplication {

    private final static Logger LOGGER = Logger
        .getLogger(BatchCloudApplication.class.getName());

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(BatchCloudApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

The job configuration code is below:

```
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.builder.JdbcCursorItemReaderBuilder;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;

@Configuration
@Import({DataSourceConfiguration.class})
public class JobConfiguration {

    private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(JobConfiguration.class);

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private DataSourceConfiguration dataSourceConfig;

    @Bean
    public Job job() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("job").flow(step1()).end().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step1() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
            .<DemandType, DemandType>chunk(1)
            .reader(itemReader())
            .processor(processor())
            .writer(writer())
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcCursorItemReader<DemandType> itemReader() {
        return new JdbcCursorItemReaderBuilder<DemandType>()
                        .dataSource(dataSourceConfig.dataSource())
                        .name("demandTypeReader")
                        .sql("select DEMAND_TYPE_ID, DEMAND_TYPE_NM from DEMAND_TYPE_DEFINITION")
                        .rowMapper(new DemandTypeRowMapper())
                        .build();

    }

    @Bean
    public DemandTypeProcessor processor() {
        return new DemandTypeProcessor();
    }


    @Bean
    public DemandTypeWriter writer() {
        return new DemandTypeWriter();
    }
}
```

The datasource configuration is below:

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;

@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@btln001091:41521/FWDSAT");
    dataSource.setUsername("APPFWDS_U1_AT02");
    dataSource.setPassword("APPFWDS_U1_AT02");

    return dataSource;
    }
}
```

The pom.xml is pasted:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>example</groupId>
<artifactId>batch-cloud</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>batch-cloud</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud-task.version>2.0.0.RELEASE</spring-cloud-task.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-task</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
        <version>10.2.0.5.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-task-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud-task.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The whole stack trace is below:

```
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.3.RELEASE)

2018-07-24 22:11:14.946  INFO 12120 --- [           main] c.t.w.b.WfmBatchCloudApplication         : Starting WfmBatchCloudApplication on L094345 with PID 12120 (C:\ccviews\wfm-batch-cloud\target\classes started by t837704 in C:\ccviews\wfm-batch-cloud)
2018-07-24 22:11:14.950  INFO 12120 --- [           main] c.t.w.b.WfmBatchCloudApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-07-24 22:11:15.010  INFO 12120 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@69b2283a: startup date [Tue Jul 24 22:11:15 PDT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-07-24 22:11:15.370  INFO 12120 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'transactionManager' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.cloud.task.configuration.SimpleTaskConfiguration; factoryMethodName=transactionManager; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in org.springframework.cloud.task.configuration.SimpleTaskConfiguration] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration; factoryMethodName=transactionManager; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/SimpleBatchConfiguration.class]]
2018-07-24 22:11:15.707  INFO 12120 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.task.batch.configuration.TaskBatchAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.task.batch.configuration.TaskBatchAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$23124f4a] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-07-24 22:11:15.716  INFO 12120 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9da2a3be] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-07-24 22:11:15.767  INFO 12120 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.task.batch.listener.BatchEventAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.task.batch.listener.BatchEventAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6b68594d] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-07-24 22:11:15.814  INFO 12120 --- [           main] o.s.j.d.DriverManagerDataSource          : Loaded JDBC driver: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
2018-07-24 22:11:17.307 DEBUG 12120 --- [           main] o.s.c.t.c.SimpleTaskConfiguration        : Using org.springframework.cloud.task.configuration.DefaultTaskConfigurer TaskConfigurer
2018-07-24 22:11:17.309 DEBUG 12120 --- [           main] o.s.c.t.c.DefaultTaskConfigurer          : No EntityManager was found, using DataSourceTransactionManager
2018-07-24 22:11:18.518 DEBUG 12120 --- [           main] o.s.c.t.r.s.TaskRepositoryInitializer    : Initializing task schema for oracle10g database
2018-07-24 22:11:19.404  INFO 12120 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executing SQL script from class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/task/schema-oracle10g.sql]
2018-07-24 22:11:20.451  INFO 12120 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executed SQL script from class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/task/schema-oracle10g.sql] in 1046 ms.
2018-07-24 22:11:21.883  INFO 12120 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2018-07-24 22:11:21.891  INFO 12120 --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase 0
2018-07-24 22:11:24.305 DEBUG 12120 --- [           main] o.s.c.t.r.support.SimpleTaskRepository   : Creating: TaskExecution{executionId=0, parentExecutionId=null, exitCode=null, taskName='slotCalculation', startTime=Tue Jul 24 22:11:21 PDT 2018, endTime=null, exitMessage='null', externalExecutionId='null', errorMessage='null', arguments=[]}
2018-07-24 22:11:24.363  INFO 12120 --- [           main] c.t.w.b.WfmBatchCloudApplication         : Started WfmBatchCloudApplication in 9.781 seconds (JVM running for 10.455)
2018-07-24 22:11:24.366  INFO 12120 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.b.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner   : Running default command line with: []
2018-07-24 22:11:25.363  INFO 12120 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.r.s.JobRepositoryFactoryBean     : No database type set, using meta data indicating: ORACLE
2018-07-24 22:11:26.519  INFO 12120 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.r.s.JobRepositoryFactoryBean     : No database type set, using meta data indicating: ORACLE
2018-07-24 22:11:26.521  INFO 12120 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : No TaskExecutor has been set, defaulting to synchronous executor.
2018-07-24 22:11:31.035  INFO 12120 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader      : Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [org/springframework/jdbc/support/sql-error-codes.xml]
2018-07-24 22:11:31.132  INFO 12120 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory    : SQLErrorCodes loaded: [DB2, Derby, H2, HDB, HSQL, Informix, MS-SQL, MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, Sybase]
2018-07-24 22:11:31.334  INFO 12120 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-07-24 22:11:33.814 DEBUG 12120 --- [           main] o.s.c.t.r.support.SimpleTaskRepository   : Updating: TaskExecution with executionId=38 with the following {exitCode=1, endTime=Tue Jul 24 22:11:31 PDT 2018, exitMessage='null', errorMessage='java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:800)
  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:781)
  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335)
  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255)
  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243)
  at com.telus.workforcemgmt.batchcloud.WfmBatchCloudApplication.main(WfmBatchCloudApplication.java:19)
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [INSERT into BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION(JOB_EXECUTION_ID, JOB_INSTANCE_ID, START_TIME, END_TIME, STATUS, EXIT_CODE, EXIT_MESSAGE, VERSION, CREATE_TIME, LAST_UPDATED, JOB_CONFIGURATION_LOCATION) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("FWDS_AT02"."BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION"."START_TIME")
; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("FWDS_AT02"."BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION"."START_TIME")

  at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:246)
  at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
  at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1402)
  at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:620)
  at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:850)
  at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:905)
  at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:910)
  at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcJobExecutionDao.saveJobExecution(JdbcJobExecutionDao.java:157)
  at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.createJobExecution(SimpleJobRepository.java:149)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.j'}
2018-07-24 22:11:37.461 ERROR 12120 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:800) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:781) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
  at com.telus.workforcemgmt.batchcloud.WfmBatchCloudApplication.main(WfmBatchCloudApplication.java:19) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [INSERT into BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION(JOB_EXECUTION_ID, JOB_INSTANCE_ID, START_TIME, END_TIME, STATUS, EXIT_CODE, EXIT_MESSAGE, VERSION, CREATE_TIME, LAST_UPDATED, JOB_CONFIGURATION_LOCATION) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("FWDS_AT02"."BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION"."START_TIME")
; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("FWDS_AT02"."BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION"."START_TIME")

  at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:246) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1402) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:620) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:850) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:905) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:910) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcJobExecutionDao.saveJobExecution(JdbcJobExecutionDao.java:157) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.createJobExecution(SimpleJobRepository.java:149) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
  at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:197) ~[spring-aop-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294) ~[spring-tx-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean$1.invoke(AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean.java:181) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy46.createJobExecution(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
  at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:131) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
  at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:197) ~[spring-aop-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy55.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
  at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.execute(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:163) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.executeLocalJobs(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:179) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.launchJobFromProperties(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:134) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.run(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:128) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:797) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
  ... 5 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("FWDS_AT02"."BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION"."START_TIME")

  at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:113) ~[ojdbc14-10.2.0.5.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.5.0"]
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:331) ~[ojdbc14-10.2.0.5.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.5.0"]
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:288) ~[ojdbc14-10.2.0.5.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.5.0"]
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:754) ~[ojdbc14-10.2.0.5.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.5.0"]
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:219) ~[ojdbc14-10.2.0.5.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.5.0"]
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:972) ~[ojdbc14-10.2.0.5.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.5.0"]
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1192) ~[ojdbc14-10.2.0.5.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.5.0"]
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3415) ~[ojdbc14-10.2.0.5.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.5.0"]
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3499) ~[ojdbc14-10.2.0.5.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.5.0"]
  at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.lambda$update$0(JdbcTemplate.java:855) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:605) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
  ... 41 common frames omitted
```

Comment: You are using a ojdbc14 jar which is a JDK 1.4 driver. Can you update it to have ojdbc8 (if you're using jdk8) ?

Comment: @warge, I updated it to ojdbc8-12.2.0.1, but still have the same error.

Comment: The BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION.START_TIME column should be nullable. Can you check if it is ? (and modify it if not)

Comment: @wargre, yes, it worked. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I wrote an answer about that to keep track more easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [DDL that is inside Spring Batch](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/master/spring-batch-core/src/main/resources/org/springframework/batch/core) project, BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION.START_TIME should accept null value.

You should check if this `BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION.START_TIME` column is nullable on your database and set it to nullable if not.